# R - Understanding the behaviour of &&

Tags: r, logical-operators

Why does `c(T, T, T) && c(NULL, F, F)` evaluate to `[1] FALSE` but `T && NULL` throw an error `Error in T && NULL : invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'`?

It looks like in the first example, `&&` skips the first pair of arguments `T && NULL` and returns the evaluation of the second pair instead `T && F`. But I was always under the impression that `&&` only evaluates the first pair and so would have predicted it to throw an error like it does in the second example.

Comment: Did you run `c(NULL, F, F)` to see what it returns? You can't have NULL in an atomic vector. Did you mean to have an `NA` value or something?

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, it had totally slipped my mind that `c(NULL, F, F)` evaluates to `[1] FALSE FALSE`. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null is not a valid boolean type. you should use `is.null()`.

The result is:

```
 > c(NULL, F, F)
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

So I would suggest using `is.null()`

```
> is.null(NULL)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Of course, I forgot `c(NULL, F, F)` evaluates to `[1] FALSE FALSE` in my haste to post. Thank you Bill.